# "The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation" 3202

Tags: sql-server, backup

I backup SQL Server database and it fails

BACKUP DATABASE dd TO
DISK = '\backupServer\backups\dd.bak'
WITH
COMPRESSION,
CHECKSUM,
NOFORMAT, INIT 
, BlockSize = 65536
, BufferCount = 2200
, MaxTransferSize = 4194304

The backup size is 3TB and I have 6TB free space on bacup server.
I am using backup parameters per SQLCAT whitepaper.

Everything works ok when I backup to local HDD and it always fails when I backup to network share. After about 6 hours. Can't find why.

Thank you.

Yes. The backup over the network is fastest and saves me 3Tb of local disk space :) Thanks for pointing to the memory issue. I left 4Gb to OS and it worked!

Comment: Have you tried performing a local backup and then doing a manual copy over to your network share?  Might help eliminate something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up large databases over the network is not recommended.  This will steal all the memory from the database engine and give it to the system cache.

Comment: I concur with Denny. The error that you are receiving is because of the file system format of the network share. Please take the backup locally and move it to the network share using tools like ROBOCOPY. It helps in many ways

Comment: The backup over the network is fastest and saves me 3Tb of local disk space :) Thanks for pointing to the memory issue. I left 4Gb to OS and it worked!